# Parse string in WP8 C#

Tags: c#, string, parsing, windows-phone-8

I have a string that looks like:

```
jQuery18309175745982483048_8380382834({"d":{"__type":"locatorservice.DataTemplate.LocatorResults","ResultData":[{"Address1":"Main Street 1","Address2":"","City":"New York","State":"SN","Zip":"04832","Country":"GER","Latitude":50.29482,"Longitude":12.3242,"StoreId":"32425"},{"Address1":"Main Street 3","Address2":"","City":"New York","State":"SN","Zip":"03242","Country":"GER","Latitude":54.29482,"Longitude":17.3242,"StoreId":"33434"}
```

And now I only want in a foreach loop the Latitude, the Longitude and the Address and the City of both. But how can I parse that string?

Comment: use a JSON parser

Comment: Looks like it's a result from a JSONP request. If you can remove the JSONP parameter and make it a regular JSON object, then you could use a regular JSON parser.

Comment: Have you a good tutorial for a JSON parser?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-to-parse-json-in-c

Comment: I don't see how your question is related to WP8 programming.
Are you using JSONP?

Comment: Hi, the json string you are given here is not in correct format. So, it will not be directly parsed.

Comment: I take only the part from the first '[' to the other ']' and than I can parse the data with a JSON parser.

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert it to Json
2. Use http://json2csharp.com/ to obtain the class in which you will put the result of parsing
3. `RootElement Result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootElement>(JsonString);`

Don't forget `using Newtonsoft.Json;`